# Input input values in ord()

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a Ceaser cipher  as a homework assignment and I need to be able to input an input value into the "`ord()`" instead of a character but am unable to.

```
a=input('Original Message: ')    
a= str(a)    
ord(a)-96    
print (ord(a)-96)
```

Comment: Well `ord` only takes characters. What you can do is loop through the input string and call `ord` on the characters.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Please review [ask] and show us what you've tried. Additionally, if this is homework, please say so. People will usually offer better explanations for homework, rather than focusing on solving the issue.

Comment: @JimFasarakis-Hilliard, is there a reason you didn't type that in the "answer" box?